# Community♦ のプロフィールを新しくしましょう！

Tags: 機能の要求, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

スタック・オーバーフローには [Community♦](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) という謎のユーザーがいます。

放置されている質問を突然サイトトップに持ってきたり、システムによる自動処理の名義として使われたり、そんな影武者です。（参考: [Community ユーザーというのは誰ですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1418/8000)）

今は英語版と同じプロフィールになっていますが、日本語版で自由に変えることができます。

> Hi, I'm not really a person.
>
> I'm a background process that helps keep this site clean!
>
> I do things like
>
> - Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention
> - Own community questions and answers so nobody gets unnecessary reputation from them
> - Own downvotes on spam/evil posts that get permanently deleted
> - Own suggested edits from anonymous users
> - [Remove abandoned questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/92006)

どんなプロフィールがいいでしょうか。皆さんのアイデアをお聞かせください。

- 名前は Community、コミュニティ、あるいは・・・
- 居場所は<del>石狩DC</del> `サーバールーム` とか
  <sub>※StackExchangeはニューヨーク（[正確に言うとニュージャージー州](http://blog.serverfault.com/2015/03/05/how-we-upgrade-a-live-data-center/)）のDCを使っているそうです</sub>
- 自己紹介も素直に訳さなくていいらしい

Comment: 日本語版だけで変えるかを聞いています。できれば、自由にかけます。英語の直訳もいいですが、ちょっと面白いことを入れたかったら、全然いいです。

Comment: 表示名も「コミュニティー」に変えられますよ。[ポルトガル版](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/comunidade)にも。

Comment: 文面はFAQにあるものが使えそうですね。 http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/1418/8000

Comment: 居場所が石狩DCだと名前はさくらちゃんですかね（

Comment: @jmac 実際にはサーバーってどのあたりにあるんでしょう。アメリカですか？

Comment: @unarist ニューヨークとオレゴン州(バックアップ)だったと思います。

Comment: @jmac そういえばメタのCommunity♦は英語のままになってます http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=profile

Answer (score 2):

以下のような感じはいかがでしょうか？

> こんにちは、世話人です。
>
> 私はこのサイトが円滑に運営されるように働くボットです。 
>   つまり、プログラムされたロボットです。「ピポ、ピポッ...」
>
> 以下の様なことをしています。
>
> - 未回答の質問を、１時間毎にランダムに、一覧のトップにピックアップして、目立つようにしています。
> - 削除されたスパム・悪意のある投稿へのマイナス投票を引き受けます
> - 匿名アカウントからの編集リクエストのオーナーになります
> - 放棄されたと思われる質問を削除します

以下の「comunity questions and answers」が何を指しているのか、よくわからなかったので、この部分の言及は避けました。

> - Own community questions and answers so nobody gets unnecessary reputation from them

Comment: community questions and answersは「community wiki (コミュニティウィキ)」を示しています。その投稿はだれでも書き加えることができるので、信用度（投稿のオーナー）がCommunity Userになります。

Comment: 「community wiki (コミュニティウィキ)」って何でしょうか？何処で見ることが出来ますか？「タグwiki」のこと？

Comment: http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki

Comment: 上記のヘルプ見ましたが、コミュニティwiki が何なのか、まったくイメージできませんでした。

Comment: http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki  

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts  

この２つのヘルプを見たら、なんとなく分かってきました。
しかし、「コミュニティwiki」は、stackoverflowの初心者には何のことを言っているのか分かりづらいので、プロフィールには載せないほうが良いかもしれません。

Comment: Communityユーザーの仕事としてもあまり目立たないものですしね…（逆にそこから「コミュニティWikiってなんだろう？」と興味を持たせるのもありですが）

Comment: 日本人はキャラクター好きなので、キャラクター作って、名前を付けてもいいかも知れませんね。「スタッキー」とか「Mr. Stack」とか...

Comment: 9walkさん、ありがとうございます！適用しました。場所は「サーバー室」にしました。

Comment: 「削除されたスパム・悪意のある投稿へのマイナス投票を引き受けます」と言うところの「引き受けます」という言い回しを「行います」にした方が良いかもしれません。