# コミュニティ♦ユーザーというのは誰ですか？

Tags: サポート, よくある質問

ちゃんと[プロフィールページ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/-1)もあります。時々質問を編集したりもしているようです。これはどういう存在ですか？

しかもマイナス投票しかしていないようです。

[←FAQ目次に戻る](/q/1484)

Answer (score 9):

### コミュニティ♦︎ユーザーというのは誰ですか？

これは自動処理をさせるためのボットで、実在する人ではありません。[プロフィール](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1)で説明されている通り:

> こんにちは、世話人です。
>
> 私はこのサイトが円滑に運営されるように働くボットです。 
>   つまり、プログラムされたロボットです。「ピポ、ピポッ...」
>
> 以下の様なことをしています。
>
> - 未回答の質問を、１時間毎にランダムに、一覧のトップにピックアップして、目立つようにしています。
> - 削除されたスパム・悪意のある投稿へのマイナス投票を引き受けます
> - 匿名アカウントからの編集リクエストのオーナーになります
> - [放棄されたと思われる質問を削除します](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006)
>
> * <sup>30日以上更新がなく、最低でも1つスコアが0の回答があり、他の回答のスコアも0以下である質問。ロックされているかクローズされた質問は対象外です。コミュニティ♦︎ユーザーによってアゲられる質問は1時間に最大1つまで。</sup>

古い[未解決](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/ok-now-define-answered/) (英語) の質問をランダムにつっつくことで、質問を最後に編集したユーザーとして名前が表示されることがありますが、それは質問の一覧でだけです。質問の個別ページでは表示されません。

[image: カタカナバージョン]

マイナス票ばかりなのは、削除された投稿のマイナス票をすべて託されているからです。

他にも:

- コミュニティWikiな質問や回答のオーナーを引き受け、他の人が信用度を無用に受け取らないようにします
- タグWiki、権限の説明ページ、ヘルプページ、モデレーター選挙用ページの所有者です
- 編集内容が衝突するかもしれない編集リクエストを却下します
- モデレーターや10kユーザーの注意を引くため、問題のありそうな投稿を通報します
- サイトの定期評価や選挙に関連するメタへの投稿の所有者です
- 編集リクエストがさらに編集された場合、裏で自動的に賛成票を投じます
- 削除されたユーザーの懸賞の所有者です
- スパム投稿をロック・削除します
- サイト移動後の投稿やサイト移動が却下された投稿をロックします

---

[Stack ExchangeメタのFAQより](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19738/157841)