# リストの中で埋没してしまう質問について

Tags: 討議

お世話になっております。

stackoverflowに置いて、何か質問を投稿した後、長期間回答がつかずにいると設定したタグを監視しているユーザがいたとしても多くの質問に埋没してしまいそのまま回答を得ることができなくなってしまうように思われます。
そこで質問なのですが、

1. 本サービスをよく利用している方々は埋没してしまった投稿を目にする方法があるのですか？
2. 投稿をアクティブ順で上に上げるために、軽微な編集を加える行為はコミュニティにとってやはり悪影響なのでしょうか？
3. 上記の行為が推奨されないものだとしたら、拡散力のないユーザは回答を期待することを諦めるべきなのでしょうか？

皆さんのご意見を聞きたいです。

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. トップページの質問一覧を一番下まで行くと、[未解決の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/unanswered)というリンクがあり、こちらでまだ解決していない質問を確認することができます。利用するユーザー次第ですが、自分のお気に入りタグでまだ回答が付いて無さそうなものを、私は時々チェックしています。

   また、運任せになる部分はありますが、まだ解決していないと思われる過去の質問を[システムがランダムに選んで質問一覧のトップに上げる仕組みがあります](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1419/3060)。
2. 内容の変更を伴わない、リストの一番上に上げるだけが目的の編集(空白や改行を入れたり消したりするだけ)は基本的に**NG**です。
   些細なことでも構わないので、質問後でも自分で調べて分かったことなどがあればそれらの情報を質問に含める努力をしてもらった方が、コミュニティからの印象は良いでしょう。
3. 自分でも努力をしてるけど回答が付かない場合には、[**お礼**を使って回答を募る方法があります](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)。
   スタック・オーバーフローでは質問や回答などの行動によって「信用度」というポイントを得られますが、この信用度を元に自分の質問を一定期間注目させることができます。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。質問を上げてくれる仕組みがあるのですね。
お礼という方法があるのも忘れていました。ではお礼を出すことができるほど信頼度を持たないユーザはまず信頼度を高める作業をした方が良いということでしょうか？

Comment: 一定の制限が無いと「使い放題」になってしまいお礼(という仕組み)が意味を成しませんし、スタック・オーバーフローは「コミュニティ=助け合いの場」であることを考えると、ある程度の信頼度が必要なのは自然な仕組みでしょう。使い始めたばかりのユーザーにとってはもどかしいかもしれませんが、継続して利用しているうちに自然と獲得できる仕組みにはなっています。 - ヘルプ: [信用度とは何ですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

Answer (score 9):

とても良いご質問だと思います。

回答がなかなかつかない場合、質問者がすべきことは自分の試行錯誤を追記し、情報をより具体的かつ詳細にすることです。「分からないなりにこういうことをしてみたのだけど、上手くいかなかった」などと、**自分が問題解決に向けて努力していることを追記してみてください**。

質問の内容を変えない軽微な修正を何度も繰り返すことは**やめてください**。何度も「アクティブな質問」リストの上にのぼることになり、迷惑です。

まだ有効な回答が寄せられていない質問の一覧は、「質問」を「**未解決**」でフィルタすることによって見ることができます。このサイトでは自分が好きなタグを「ウォッチ」することができますが、未解決質問の一覧は更に、ウォッチしているタグでフィルタすることができます。このサイトにある程度慣れている方はこのようにして未解決の質問を見つけることができます。

[image: 「未解決」ボタン]

タグでフィルタした後の質問一覧では、より投票点数が高い質問が上位に表示されます。最初に言った質問の具体化をしていれば、自然とプラス投票が集まり、リストの上に表示されることになるでしょう。

更に、もし質問者さんが既に幾らか信用度を獲得しているなら、他に以下のことを試せます。

- 投稿に[お礼](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties)をつける。
- [チャット](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat)で丁寧に解決を頼んでみる。

質問になかなか回答が集まらないことはたびたびあります。集まらない理由は多くの場合「質問内容が曖昧でよくわからない」「質問内容が本当に難しくて分からない」「当該分野を知っているユーザーが少なくて分からない」の 3 つのどれかです。ご自身の試行錯誤を追記することによって、特に 1 つ目と 2 つ目の場合少しでも回答が集まりやすくなるようにすることができます。なかなか反応が得られないともどかしく思いますが、そのくらい難しい質問なのだと思って、情報を追加してみてください :)