# metaサイトのCommunityのプロフィールが英語のまま

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

場所 https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community
メインサイトでは日本語ですのでmetaも同じようなプロフィールにしてくださるとありがたいです。

---

Community's profile stays English in Meta.
Context:https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community.

Comment: 開発者とフォロー中です。メインサイトでは手動的に編集できますが、メタではそのオプションはないため、メインサイトのプロフィールを利用するロジックを作成する必要があります。

Comment: @jmac 他のサイトを確認したところ、[ロシア語版](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/Дух-сообщества)や、[ポルトガル語版](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/comunidade)は**翻訳されています**。何故でしょうか。([スペイン語版](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community)は英語のまま)

Comment: @sunsolararrow 編集可能になればプロフィールは[既に完成している物](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/77/community-%E3%81%AE%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%83%95%E3%82%A3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%82%92%E6%96%B0%E3%81%97%E3%81%8F%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%97%E3%82%87%E3%81%86)を使えます。