# Community♦ というユーザー名を「コミュニティ」に変更いたしました

Tags: 討議, 完了, 翻訳

追記@2020/01/16

現時点で10のプラス票が投じられましたので「コミュニティ♦」に変更いたしました。ご投票ありがとうございました！

[image: ピポッ...]

---

[Community ♦](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=profile)という英語のユーザー名を、カタカナの「コミュニティ」に変更する事が可能です。変更せずにこのまま、或いは「コミュニティ」に変更する、の何れかを回答欄でプラス投票いただけますでしょうか？（「SOjaコミュニティで再度コンセンサスを得るべきではないか」という[お声](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53204541#53204541)がありました。）

以前に、entoさんが[以下の通り](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/77/14055)プロフィール名などのアイデアを募って下さっていたのですが、少し時間が経過しましたので再度みなさんにお伺いできればと思います。

- 名前は Community、コミュニティ、あるいは・・・

関連：

- [Community ユーザーというのは誰ですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1418/14055)
- [Localize the username of the Community user on rus.SE and ja.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342006/314875)
- [Rename the Community user on localized sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252905/314875)

Comment: 「コミュニティ」は"集合"なので、"個"としてのユーザー名とするのはなんとなく違和感がありますが、かといって良い別名が思いつきません。 / StackOverflowとしてのマスコットキャラみたいなものがいればベストなんですが :-(

Comment: 以前に9walkさんが「スタッキー」とか「Mr. Stack」というキャラクター名をあげてくださっていたので、もし他にも良さそうな名前があればお教えください m_ _m。それまでは今回の投票結果の通り「コミュニティ♦」と変更させていただきますね！

Answer (score 11, accepted):

「コミュニティ♦」に変更する方が良いと思います。（理由等ございましたらこちらを編集追記いただくか、コメント欄にご投稿ください。）

Answer (score 3):

「Community♦」のままで良いと思います。（理由等ございましたらこちらを編集追記いただくか、コメント欄にご投稿ください。）